# Were prisons in Maine mixed race in 1947?

Tags: united-states, race, 1940s

In the movie *The Shawshank Redemption*, white Andy Dufresne (played by Tim Robbins) and black Ellis "Red" Redding (played by Morgan Freeman) are in the same prison.

I don't remember if it was said anytime in the movie, but Andy lived in Maine before his imprisonment, so it is very likely that Shawshank is located in Maine (state prison).

My question is, were prisons in Maine mixed race in 1947 (his year of imprisonment)?

Comment: The clincher for _The Shawshank Redemption_ being set in Maine is that [the movie is adapted from a Stephen King story](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_Seasons).

Comment: You may find that sometimes prisons segregated prisoners by race and sometimes they didn't. Tough question, I think.

Comment: @LarsBosteen do you mean that in Maine specifically or generally that there were segregated prisons in the US and there were non-segregated prisons?

Comment: Not Maine specifically, there seems to be very little on this state.

Comment: Maine is and was a very white state. In 2022 it is about 95% white. In the 1950 census, 1,221 out of Maine's 913,774 residents, or about 0.1%, identified as Black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

At least one prison in Maine counted both white and Black prisoners among its population during the 1940-1950 time period.

In the [1950 census of Knox County, Maine, enumeration district 7-36](https://1950census.archives.gov/search/?county=Knox&ed=7-36&page=1&state=ME) includes the Maine State Prison in Thomaston.

Page 3 of this ED lists, mixed among the "W" (white) prisoners, the following two people:

- Branning, Joseph, prisoner, race "Neg," M, 40, (marital status illegible), born in Hawaii
- Brown, John, prisoner, race "Neg," M, 50, never married, born in Massachusetts

[image: 1950 census Knox Co Maine]

In the [1940 census of Knox County, Maine, ED 7-38](https://catalog.archives.gov/id/127792106?objectPage=2) includes the Maine State Prison in Thomaston.

Page 2 of this ED lists, mixed among the white prisoners, the following person, who may be the same as one of those in the 1950 census:

- Brown, John, M, race "Neg," 40, single, completed 1 year of high school, born in Massachusetts, and in 1935 was in the same location (the prison)

[image: 1940 Knox County Maine census]

There are other Black inmates on other pages of both censuses. There are also Black inmates listed in the [1930 census of Maine State Prison](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:9396-DQSQ-XZ?i=490&cat=1036356).

The [Wikipedia page for Maine State Prison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maine_State_Prison) claims, without references, that in 1927 the prison held three Black prisoners in addition to 197 white prisoners.

Note that Maine is and was a very white state. In 2023 it is about 95% white. In the 1950 census, 1,221 out of Maine's 913,774 residents, or about 0.1%, identified as Black.